ASP.NET webform Invalid URL loads page
Url : localhost:12345/about - valid; loads about page.
Url : localhost:12345/about/anything -  invalid; shouldn't load - but it also loads about page
Url localhost:12345/about/anything is not a valid page and should result in an error.
Any ideas? Thanks

Actually, that is a "feature", and not a bug.
One of my favorite features of ASP.NET pages is what we call "friendly URL's".
This is a ASP.NET feature that allows you to replace "messy" or often "ugly" URL's with a friendly URL.
Say you want a web page that looks nice, and allows the user (or your links, or URLs code) to load a quote number from your database and display that quote.
Often, one would use query parameters in the URL.
Say, like this:
  www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes/?City=Edmonton&QuoteNumber=123456

Now, I don't think the above looks all that great. However, computer users by nature think of folders and files.
Hence, with a friendly URL then above becomes this:
 www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes/Edmonton/123456

Not only does the above URL look oh so much nicer?
Users will often associate the above with a folder like hierarchy.
Hence, some users will even start to type in:
  www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes/New York/545222

In other words, while the above works much the same as a messy URL parameter?
The above folder "New York" and "545222" don't exist. Only the page Quotes.aspx exists, and the rest is "fake" or not really an existing URL. This also means you can share that link, and it looks far better then the first example with URL and using URL query parameters.
Want to see another existing example? Why of course this VERY post you made here!!!
Stack Overflow was written using ASP.NET, and hence Stack Overflow uses this friendly URL feature. Your current URL as you read this post is thus:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78817043/asp-net-webform-invalid-url-loads-page

So, the page called "questions" exists, but after that, there is not a folder called 78817043, and of course after that the URL of your "question" also does not exist.
So, friendly URLs are a great feature, since such links are more readable, easy to share, and as I pointed out, while computer users "struggle" with reading or typing in URLs with ugly parameters?
With friendly URLs, then some users will even type in the Quote number, if they want to view quote 456, then they can type in this:
  www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes/456

So, the web page "456" does not exist, but from a user point of view, they think it does. The end result is you presenting nice looking URLs, and ones that look like some existing folder. In above, then the page Quotes.aspx exists, but everything after quotes can be "made up" by you the developer, and thus they are all valid URL's.
So, I could even say show all pending quotes like this:
 www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes/Pending

So, additional parameters are freely legal and can be added using the forward slash. So, while it appears like a legal URL, any additional forward slashes and values after the valid web page simply become parameters that code behind can pick up.
So, this suggests that your site has friendly URL's enabled, and as such, then additional parts in the URL after the existing base page are not only ignored, but also legal. Of course if your code behind does not process or do anything with those extra values, then no damage or issue will occur, and no error is generated.
The other feature of friendly URL's is the file extension is not required. So, often this feature is turned on EVEN when not using the parameters feature, but to simply make web pages look cleaner, and the ".aspx" suffix is not required.
Hence, say this URL
 www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes.aspx

With friendly URLs, then this becomes legal:
 www.mycoolwebsite/Quotes

If you need/want that example URL to fail?
You have several choices, and one choice would be to turn off friendly URL's. However, you would have to be 100% if not 200% sure that users of the site are not already using friendly URLs, and have not bookmarked and saved friendly URL's. So, turning off the feature for an existing site is not recommended.
The other choice is on page load event is to test/check for any friendly parameters, and then either issue an error in code, or perhaps navigate to some other page. So, on page load, you can test/check/get these parameters like this:
        Dim fURL As IList(Of String)
        fURL = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments

        If fURL.Count = 2 Or fURL.Count = 3 Then

So, if the user has not entered any "friendly" part of the URL, then the .Count  will be 0.
I of course am a big fan of URLs, and they often add a really professional touch to your site, but are also very readable and useful from a user's point of view. Sharing of links are easer to read, and typing in some quote number as per above examples also is far easier for end users. And the bonus part is no ".aspx" suffix need be typed in for all of the web pages for that site.
So take a look at THIS CURRENT question you are reading, and take a quick look at the URL being used for this very web page. This will give you an idea of how this feature is used.
So, I would not worry or care if some user types in some URL that does not exist, since as I stated, this is a "feature" and not a "bug", and a great feature at that. You could turn off the feature, and thus such illegal URL's will trigger an error, but I don't suggest turning off this feature.
